# Rails Flash was working, now it's not

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Suddenly flash and params aren't working for me. Even my normal flash error/success messages don't work.

This is just one sample - I have the following in a view:

```
 <%= link_to 'New Comment', new_comment_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary', :onclick => flash[:worequest_id] = @worequest.id %>
```

And in the new comment form:

```
 <% if flash[:worequest_id] != nil %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :worequest_id, :value => flash[:worequest_id] %>
```

I have been using flash to pass data between a view and a form in quite a few places in my Rails app.  Now, none of them are working!!

Could I have set some configuration that would turn off flash and params?

I appreciate your help!!

UPDATE

I read on another post, where someone was having "session problems"  with FLASH.    Where would I look for session problems?

UPDATE2

I added the following to the view that receives the data from the flash:

```
    <% if flash[:worequest_id].blank?  %>
      <h3>flash blank</h3>
    <% end %>
```

And "flash blank" showed up.

Really - This has been in many places of my app for months.  And now it's not working!!!!!!!

UPDATE3

I also tried this:

```
<% flash.keep[:worequest_id] = @worequest.id %>
```

Is there a rails config file that deals with session?  Maybe I messed up a parameter or something.

UDPATE4

This is the only line in my initializers/session_store.rb file:

```
Ndeavor::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_ndeavor_session'
```

UPDATE5

Params don't work either !!!!!

```
params[:worequest_id]
```

UPDATE6

I just created a new app from scratch using Rails 3.2.11 and flash and params are working fine.  So, it's not the version of Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the jbuilder gem and now flash and params are working.  It has to be something I did, because I just tried jbuilder in another app, and it didn't break flash.  I'm going to try and figure out why my use of the gem caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Im a bit confused about what/how you're trying to achieve.
Have you looked at the output produced by this?

```
<%= link_to 'New Comment', new_comment_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary', :onclick => flash[:worequest_id] = @worequest.id %>
```

Comment: Yes, on the new comment form, the flash is empty.  I also tried param, and it's empty.  They both worked last week. I have upgraded Rails to 3.2.11.  Now, they aren't working anywhere in my app.  But, I'm not sure that the rails upgrade caused them to stop working.

Comment: What I'm trying to achive is = When the user is looking at a request (worequest), they can click the "New Comment" button and it takes them to the Comment form.  The comment has a foreign key to the Worequest.  I'm using flash to carry forward the Worequest.id for the new comment record.

Comment: I searched the Rails issue logs on github.  But, I'm not finding anything.

Comment: Seems like you're getting a lot of the things wrong.
You're abusing the flash.
The point of the :onclick atribute is to execute javascript function, but you're assigning an expression that evaluates to @worequest.id.
You're wrong in thinking that somehow the flash will be set when the user clicks the link. It's set when the template is rendered. 
Seems like the Comments are nested resource of Worequest and you need to pass the id as a part of the url. Does Worequest `has_many` comments?

Comment: It doesn't matter how I try to use flash or params - they don't work in my app.  I created a scratch app just to see if it was because 3.2.11 version I upgraded to - but, flash and params work fine in the scratch app.

Comment: Storing something in the flash in the template is a bad idea. if you'd like to preserve something between requests in the flash, you'd usually set it in the controller.
You need to stop looking for the reason the flash stopped working and concentrate on solving the problem the right way.
Have you defined nested routes for worequest's comments like
resources :worequest { resources :comments } ?

Comment: Aren't error notifications a good use of flash?  Because they aren't working either -   <%= f.error_notification %>

Comment: Are you using simple_form gem? error_notification has nothing to do with the flash. It's a method on the form builder object which checks if the corresponding model object has any errors.